# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: androidx.test.uiautomator.StaleObjectException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I was trying to run this on the Android TV i see the Appium is able to click on all the buttons and input the data in text box except the very first one. i have to click on it then wait and used send keys to see if it solves the issue but no luck. can someone help me on this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq32o.png)

```
Base.Java

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Base {
    
    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> capabalities() throws MalformedURLException {
        
        File file = new File ("src");
        File fs = new File(file,"TVTestApp_ct.apk");
        
        DesiredCapabilities capabalities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabalities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"uiautomator2");
        capabalities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Automation");
        capabalities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabalities);
        return driver;
    }

}

HomeScreen.Java

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByClassName;
import org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class HomeScreen extends Base {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = capabalities();
        
        driver.findElementById("com.tvexample.tvtestapp:id/editText").sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElementById("com.tvexample.tvtestapp:id/editText1").sendKeys("1234")         
        
    }


}
```

Logs:

```
Jun 21, 2021 2:11:47 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: androidx.test.uiautomator.StaleObjectException
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'TXCDTL20CT1696', ip: '135.70.71.74', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: C:\Users\cg517n\Documents\e..., appPackage: com.tvexample.tvtestapp, automationName: uiautomator2, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {app: C:\Users\cg517n\Documents\e..., automationName: uiautomator2, deviceName: Automation, platformName: android}, deviceApiLevel: 28, deviceManufacturer: unknown, deviceModel: sdk_google_atv_x86, deviceName: emulator-5554, deviceScreenDensity: 320, deviceScreenSize: 1920x1080, deviceUDID: emulator-5554, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, pixelRatio: 2, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 9, statBarHeight: 0, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 1080, left: 0, top: 0, width: 1920}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 75f6f7db-21e8-407e-8a53-59271e4e9e02
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:45)
    at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement.execute(AndroidElement.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
    at HomeScreen.main(HomeScreen.java:18)
```

Comment: What is the 18 line in HomeScreen?

Comment: those are few suggestion from internet that i have tried and i have commented those out. For the convivence i have removed them.

Answer (score 0):

an example:

```
private void findUIByText(String t,String b,int n){
    Log.d(TAG,"findUIByText");
    //autoCheckAndClick.autoClick();
    int i = 0;
    UiObject2 object2 = null;
    while (i < 6) {
        i++;
        object2 = mDevice.findObject(
                By.textContains(t)
        );
        try {
            if(object2 != null){
                Log.d(TAG,"not null");
                if(Objects.equals(b, "TRUE")){
                    object2.click(1000);
                }else {
                    object2.click();
                }
                break;
            }

        } catch (StaleObjectException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"StaleObjectException");
            if (n < 4){
                findUIByText(t,b,n+1);
            }
        }
        toSleep(500);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).